# BadZipFile while downloading from Kaggle

Tags: python

I am trying to download and unzip Kaggle dataset by python script(Python 3.5), but I get an error.

```
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile
import csv
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs/download/test.csv.zip'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
c=ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.read()))
```

After running this code, I get the following error.

**BadZipFile: File is not a zip file**

How can I get rid of this error? What's the cause?

Comment: This link is not publicly accessible. Where are you including the access privileges in the program? is this the complete program?

Comment: Something like this should work: http://ramhiser.com/2012/11/23/how-to-download-kaggle-data-with-python-and-requests-dot-py/

Comment: kmario23 is right, you should login to the site by python code before downloading the file. Otherwise, the request to the URL will not be a zip file.

Comment: The test.csv.zip file seems to special: I can download it to my Mac and unzip it without issues. But when unzipping it with Python ZipFile library I get your error. So the workaround is probably to download and extract in two separated steps.
The Unix command "file" says: "Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract" which looks correct. It's just Python (and only this one file) that does not understand it. Usually, @5884106 's code works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using requests module and some minor fix to http://ramhiser.com/2012/11/23/how-to-download-kaggle-data-with-python-and-requests-dot-py/ the solution is:

```
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile
import csv
import requests

# The direct link to the Kaggle data set
data_url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs/download/test.csv.zip'

# The local path where the data set is saved.
local_filename = "test.csv.zip"

# Kaggle Username and Password
kaggle_info = {'UserName': "my_username", 'Password': "my_password"}

# Attempts to download the CSV file. Gets rejected because we are not logged in.
r = requests.get(data_url)

# Login to Kaggle and retrieve the data.
r = requests.post(r.url, data = kaggle_info)

# Writes the data to a local file one chunk at a time.
f = open(local_filename, 'wb')
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 512 * 1024): # Reads 512KB at a time into memory
    if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
        f.write(chunk)
f.close()

c = ZipFile(local_filename)
```